# Trigger :Add an old value with the new value

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create an trigger on phpmyadmin.
My objective is to create a trigger that add the old value of a row with the new value (inserted with a form).

It's for managing the student dues, so if a student already paid $100, and pay $150 more the other time, the trigger have to add the old value ($100) with the new received value ($150), and the field 'already_paid' in the db is now $250.

I've tried something simple like this, but it didn't worked.

( BEFORE UPDATE )

```
SET @resultat = already_paid + new.already_paid
UPDATE student_dues
SET already_paid = @resultat
WHERE student_due_id = new.student_due_id

&

UPDATE student_dues
SET versement = versement + new.versement
WHERE student_due_id = new.student_due_id
```

Comment: Before update ON what table?

Comment: On the same table, all the process is on the 'student_due' table

Answer (score 0):

You cannot action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger. Since already have the row to be updated which is the row, which is being updated, then you don't need an UPDATE

```
SET new.already_paid = old.already_paid + new.already_paid;
```

is all you need.

And you don't need a trigger a standalone update statement is all you need

```
UPDATE student_dues
SET already_paid = already_paid + <value to update with>
WHERE student_due_id = <whatever>
```

I am a bit dubious about your process though given you have no record of what already_paid consists of or when.

Comment: I cannot create a trigger which, when it receives data from the form, retrieves the old value (the value entered in the db field) and adds it to the value sent by the form BEFORE updating?

Comment: Not with you, a mysql trigger only fires when a table is actioned (update/insert/delete) you cannot invoke a mysql trigger directly.

Comment: Ok thanks for that ! But I don't really understand what to do with that "SET new.already_paid = old.already_paid + new.already_paid;"

Comment: I think you need to review what mysql triggers do - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html